# parse number from a locale specific string?

Tags: iphone

I have to get the number from France-number-style string: @"30.000,00"
When I use NSNumberFormattern to parse

```
 NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
 NSNumber *priceNumberValue = [numberFormatter numberFromString:@30.000"];
```

It returned 30, my expected return is 30000
I try to use other options

```
NSLocale *vnLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fr_FR"];
[numberFormatter setLocale:vnLocale];
```

or

```
[numberFormatter setDecimalSeparator:@","];
```

but it still returns unexpected value: 30

What is the correct way for me to tell the NSNumberFormatter parse @"30.000,00"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the locale should work, but you'll have to tell the numberformatter to use the grouping separator:

```
[numberFormatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
```

If that doesn't work, the following will definitely work:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setDecimalSeparator:@","];
[numberFormatter setGroupingSeparator:@"."];
[numberFormatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
NSNumber *priceNumberValue = [numberFormatter numberFromString:@"30.000,00"];
```

After checking this, it seems that the "fr-FR" locale doesn't have the properties you expect. However, using the "fr-BE" locale works fine:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fr_BE"];
[numberFormatter setLocale:locale];
[locale release];
[numberFormatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
NSNumber *priceNumberValue = [numberFormatter numberFromString:@"30.000,00"];
```